# How can I speed up my Clojure program which uses ":reload"?

Tags: clojure

I am developing a Clojure program and I use

```
(:use modulename :reload)
```

: everywhere (in about 100 clj files). This is causing everything to get slower and slower all the time. Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is easy: don't use `:reload` in your `ns` forms. It's wrong a bazillion times out of ten: `reload` is intended for REPL use, not for namespace declarations. How on earth can namespace `foo` *know* that namespace `bar` is loaded already and needs to *reload* in order for `foo` to work properly? If your setup is really so labyrinthine that this makes sense, you probably have bigger problems than your startup time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I found that having to enter (use namespace :reload) at the repl every time a change was becoming a pain as well. How do you get handle this?

Comment: I don't write use/require at the REPL at all. I just use swank and let emacs handle all the heavy lifting: `C-c` `C-k` reloads the current buffer and all its dependencies.

Comment: So you still end up reloading everything behind the scenes, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes and no, I suppose. C-c C-k arranges to only reload those namespaces which have changed since the last load. How it does this I don't know; maybe `(use [foo :reload])` does the same thing. But putting this *in your source files* is madness. You don't want your app to load every namespace a dozen times whenever it launches; only when you change something while developing.